# Установка на VirtualBox Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, ос, boot

Не могу установить на VM Linux Ubuntu 32 разрядный.

При запуске виртуальной машины выполнил стандартную процедуру с созданием виртуального диска, выбрал путь на образ и т.д. Образ iso скачал с оф. сайта. При запуске ничего не происходит. Если зайти в boot и выбрать continue boot, открывается следующий экран в котором все пункты, кроме проверки памяти ведут к моргающей строке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @VladSpirin да.

Comment: @VladSpirin выполнил это с помощью BurnAware. Создал ещё один iso через него. Или Вы не про это?

Comment: @VladSpirin так у меня так и есть. Там и стоит путь к загрузочному диску

Comment: Значит отлично, бывает там народ забывает и там проблема. Тогда только образ в этом случае. Закачай новый образ с офф.сайта, смотри чтоб внимательно это было 32 бит. С версии 17.10 и выше не поддерживает 32 бит. Далее сразу этот образ прям из папки загрузки, цепляешь без лишних манипуляций сюда и все должно быть ок

Comment: @VladSpirin уже качаю ту же версию (да, снова 32) заново

Comment: @VladSpirin к слову, не знаете чем обусловлена невозможность установить на моём 64-х разрядном аппарате в VB установить 64-x разрядную версию Ubuntu?

Comment: @VladSpirin Ubuntu 16.04.5 Desktop (32-bit) если быть точнее

Comment: Я если честно вообще не знаю зачем вам 32 бит, разве что оперативы мало

Comment: Угу, оперативной мало :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86756/discussion-between-vlad-spirin-and-alexidest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение проблемы, если были корректно соблюдены все шаги установки самого VirtualBox и ОС Ubuntu. Подробнее о шагах установки на [wikiHow](https://ru.wikihow.com/%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-Ubuntu-%D0%B2-VirtualBox).

Моя же проблема была в запрете технологии аппаратной визуализации. Разрешить или запретить использование можно в сис.обеспечении мат платы. У меня же это стандартный BIOS. Делается это в расширенных настройках изменением состояния Disabled на Enabled.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]